# unable to figure out which package update lead to change of CA certs location for python requests package

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, python-requests

I am trying to figure out which package update could have lead to change in the default CA location for python requests package. Listed below is my findings on 2 different nodes running RHEL 7.

One can check what cert-store is being used by requests package as specified below:

```
[root@compute-01 test]# python -mrequests.certs
/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

[root@compute-01 test]# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

[root@compute-01 test]# python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct 11 2015, 17:47:16) 
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> requests.__version__
'2.7.0'
```

The same thing on the other node is as follows:-

```
[root@compute-25 test]# python -m requests.certs
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/cacert.pem

[root@compute-25 test]# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

[root@compute-25 test]# python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct 11 2015, 17:47:16) 
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> requests.__version__
'2.7.0'
```

I am unable to figure out which package might have got upgraded which lead to this. I am unable to figure out what next I should check. Kindly advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One version of requests (the former) was installed by your system package manager and the latter was installed by pip.